# pymongo - LookupError: unknown encoding: idna

Tags: python3

I'm having an error with pymongo (version 3.6.0) when I try to instantiate a MongoClient. My python version is 3.7.4, running on OS X Mojave.

Does any one know how this problem can be fixed or if there is any workaround?

```
$ pip3 freeze | grep pymongo
WARNING: Could not generate requirement for distribution -ppnope 0.1.0 (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages): Parse error at "'-ppnope='": Expected W:(abcd...)
pymongo==3.6.0
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-60edd7a153e2> in <module>
----> 1 import pymongo
      2 
      3 client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://XXXXXX:27017")
      4 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/__init__.py in <module>
     79                             MAX_SUPPORTED_WIRE_VERSION)
     80 from pymongo.cursor import CursorType
---> 81 from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient
     82 from pymongo.mongo_replica_set_client import MongoReplicaSetClient
     83 from pymongo.operations import (IndexModel,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py in <module>
     51                      uri_parser,
     52                      client_session)
---> 53 from pymongo.client_options import ClientOptions
     54 from pymongo.command_cursor import CommandCursor
     55 from pymongo.cursor_manager import CursorManager

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/client_options.py in <module>
     21 from pymongo.errors import ConfigurationError
     22 from pymongo.monitoring import _EventListeners
---> 23 from pymongo.pool import PoolOptions
     24 from pymongo.read_concern import ReadConcern
     25 from pymongo.read_preferences import (make_read_preference,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py in <module>
    245 # to import the IDNA codec. Import it here, where presumably we're on the
    246 # main thread, to avoid the deadlock. See PYTHON-607.
--> 247 u'foo'.encode('idna')
    248 
    249 

LookupError: unknown encoding: idna
```